# Linear Regression - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm learning deep learning and machine learning using Tensorflow, and I need to make a prediction which the input is an histogram(per day), I introduce the date in ordinal format (736608 is 2017-10-06) and the output desired for that input is 8334.71. The problem is after some iterations the loss returns me nan.

The model:

```
def create_model(self):
    input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='input', shape=(None, 1))
    self.model = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input, units=1, name='output')

def get_training_data_from_elastic_result(self, file_path):
    result = {
        'data': np.array([], dtype=np.float32),
        'label': np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
    }
    input_json = json.load(open(file_path, 'r'))
    bucket_values = input_json['aggregations']['id']['date']['histogram']['buckets']
    for bucket in bucket_values:
        current_ordinal_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(bucket['key'] / 1000)).toordinal()
        result['data'] = np.append(arr=result['data'], values=current_ordinal_date)
        result['label'] = np.append(arr=result['label'], values=round(float(bucket['relevance_sum']['value']), 2))

    """Reshape to
    [
        [737051.],
        [737052.],
        [737053.]
    ]

    [
        [3108.11],
        [1499.51],
        [1327.35]
    ]
    """
    result['data'] = result['data'].reshape(-1, 1)
    result['label'] = result['label'].reshape(-1, 1)

    return result

def train(self, input_data, input_labels, learning_rate=0.1, num_steps=1000, display_steps=10):
        real_output = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='real_output', shape=(None, 1))
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=real_output, predictions=self.model)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss)

        for step in range(num_steps):
            _, error_value = self.session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={'input:0': input_data, 'real_output:0': input_labels})
            if (step + 1) % display_steps == 0:
                self.MODEL_LOGGER.info("Epoch: {epoch} Cost {cost}".format(
                    epoch=(step + 1),
                    cost=error_value
                ))
```

The output

```
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 1 Cost=1.06697175859e+12
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 2 Cost=1.25770053337e+34
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 3 Cost=inf
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 4 Cost=inf
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 5 Cost=inf
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 6 Cost=nan
INFO:model.model:Epoch: 7 Cost=nan
```

Comment: Hello @hyper7, you should really be scaling your `x` and `y` array values to a more manageable domain, i.e. normalize your input arrays. Your neural network is going to choke if it has to train on large integers such as unix timestamps. You can then convert back to your original scale using the maximum values from your original arrays, i.e. `x.max()` & `y.max()`, as factors after your model has finished training.